# How to reduce boilerplate for Akka HTTP Rest API in front of a database?

Tags: scala, rest, akka

Assuming you have two entities in your domain, accounts and owners. If you implement a API correctly, you typically have these apis:

1. POST account
2. GET account/{id}
3. PATCH account/{id}
4. GET accounts?$filter='city eq New York'&$limit=10&offset=3

The same would be applicable for owners. In the end, you will have to manually write a lot of duplicated code to extract parameters from rest API and a lot of code to turn those parameters into appropriate queries for your underlying data storage.

Is there any framework or approach which allows to reduce the boilerplate, a functional-like version of Apache Olingo?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't some simple home-grown approach like the one below suffice? There are a few gaps to fill in, but, unlike in a framework, you have all the freedom to organise your code as you like.

```
def createRoute[T](entityName: String,
                 create: (T) => Route, getter: (UUID) => Route,
                 patcher: (UUID) => Route,
                 lister: (Map[String, String]) => Route)
                (implicit unmarshaller: FromRequestUnmarshaller[T]) = {
pathPrefix(entityName) {
  pathEndOrSingleSlash {
    post {
      entity(as[T]) { e :T ⇒ create(e) }
    } ~
      pathPrefix(JavaUUID) { id ⇒
        pathEndOrSingleSlash {
          get {
            getter(id)
          } ~ patch {
              patcher(id)
          }
        }
      }
  }
 } ~ pathPrefix(entityName + "s") {
  parameterMap => { params: Map[String, String] => lister(params)
  }
 }
}

val apiRoutes1: Route = createRoute[Account]("account", ...) ~
                        createRoute[Owner]("owner", ...)
```

Comment: This is a good start, however one would like to abstract over the type of ID, standardize the syntax, provide optional delete  / put support, etc etc. DreamFactory in Akka is what we are looking for

Comment: CRUD-level REST API over the whole domain model? May be a good idea for some cases, I still have to see them.

Comment: What about simply adding also put, delete, plus standard params (i.e. Odata) in case of get, plus providing that in a generic fashion ?

Comment: I would like to have a library for all that, I guess :-)